# Why is the value of my database column always 0?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm using go-gorm to fetch values from a PostgreSQL database.  The relevant code is shown below:

```
type Chip struct {
    UUID    string `db:uuid`
    URL     string `db:url`
    N       int    `db:n`
    Pack_ID int    `db:pack_id`
}

func getChip(uuid string) (Chip, error) {
    var c Chip
    err := DB.Model(Chip{}).Where("uuid = ?", uuid).First(&c)
    return c, err.Error
}
```

When I pass a UUID string to `getChip`, the correct row is returned and all values are correct **except** for `c.Pack_ID`, which is always `0`.  Incidentally there is never a row for which `Pack_ID` is `0`.

Here is a screenshot from pgAdminIII, which I hope will shed some light on the problem:

[image]

Any ideas as to what might be going wrong?  I'm at a complete loss, here...

Comment: It might be useful to add some example code showing how you add the values to your database. Are you sure you didn't misspell a variable name and are using an empty variable when inserting Pack_ID?

Comment: @Jasper, the DB was populated manually with PgAdminIII.  I've checked several time and I can see no spelling error.  I'm new to postgres, however, is there a way for me to dump relevant summary information about the table?

Comment: @Jasper, there is one (potentially) relevant difference in the column name and the struct name, however.  In postgres, the column is called `pack_id`, but in the go code, it's called `Pack_ID`.  That said, shouldn't the `db:pack_id` declaration keep me out of trouble?  (Edit:  Please see the screenshot above)

Comment: Don't you mean `.Where("uuid = $1", uuid).First(&c)` given that Postgres' uses `$1, $2, $3, etc` and not `?` for parameterisation?

Comment: @elithrar, Probably :)  What's the difference, exactly?  In any case I've made the changes but my original problem persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The struct tags you're using appear to be malformed.  A struct tag [should be of the form](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag):

```
name:"value"
```

but what you've got is missing the quotes around the value:

```
name:value
```

Try correcting this.  Otherwise, the struct tag parser in Go has no chance to work, as it depends on those quotes, [as seen in the struct tag parser implementation](http://golang.org/src/reflect/type.go?s=21589:21632#L752).

With regards to specific struct tags: are you sure you're supposed to use `db`?  According to the [Gorm documentation](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm#existing-schema), you probably want to use `gorm:"column:..."`.  I was expecting your type definition to be:

```
type Chip struct {
    UUID    string `gorm:"column:uuid;primary_key"`
    URL     string `gorm:"column:url"`
    N       int    `gorm:"column:n"`
    Pack_ID int    `gorm:"column:pack_id"`
}
```